# How to use global variable in arguments to setx command in cmd (command line)

Tags: cmd, command-line, global-variables

**Performed**

```
setx /m DESKTOP %UserProfile%\Desktop
```

**Real result**

```
set DESKTOP
DESKTOP=C:\Users\dkurlyanov\Desktop
```

**Desired result**

```
set DESKTOP
DESKTOP=%UserProfile%\Desktop
```

I'm only interested in the option through the console

Comment: What happens if you escape the percent characters? The most common escape characters are `^`, `\ ` and `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct answer from "Compo"**

```
setx /m DESKTOP ^%UserProfile^%\Desktop
```